# Is there a term for speech that gradually accelerates?

Tags: meaning, terminology, speech

I was having a conversation with a friend about typing text crammedtogetherlikeso, to emulate a very quick speaking pattern. He mentioned cadence in regards to this, but I was thinking that cadence was more for rhythm in speech.

I was wondering if there existed a specific term for a gradual or sudden acceleration or deceleration in speech to convey excitment or apathy or the like. (Primarily while talking, not so much in text; though if there were a word for that it would be good to know as well.)

Comment: No, there is not a specific word. I should know as this is a great concern to me and my fellow interpreters. To speak faster or slower. To speed up suddenly. To slow down suddenly. There is a speed past which interpretation becomes impossible....

Comment: You could borrow the word *accelerando* from music notation.